# Spring Boot: Getting error "Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE" when running JUnit test from eclipse

Tags: junit, spring-boot

I'm having a little problems running JUnit tests from Eclipse directly (using the "Run As JUnit test" on the JUnit test file I want to run) on a simple Spring Boot application.

I'm using Gradle as a build tool.  Now, when running the test as a Gradle task it works just fine, but when running it as an Eclipse JUnit task it fails with the follwoing error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
```

My application.properties files does define a local MySQL database and that seems to work fine with gradle:

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

My Application Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
```

My Application test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ApplicationTests {
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you notice that for spring.datasource.url you put : instead of =? If it can't get the URL it tries to create an embedded db. Just change : to =

Comment: Nah I just found out what the problem was.  I disabled the eclipse build.  When I built the project using the eclipse builder (as opposed to doing it with gradle), the Eclipse JUnit runner started working and my tests passed.